# bloomberg api does not connect from c# even if bbcomm is activated

Tags: c#, bloomberg

I am trying to connect to bloomberg session via the C# api. I cannot connect even if bbcomm is activated and running ( my bbg terminal is running too ). Is there is something I am missing ?

Thanks for your help

Here is the code:

```
 SessionOptions sessionOptions = new SessionOptions();
        sessionOptions.ServerHost = d_host;
        sessionOptions.ServerPort = d_port;

        System.Console.WriteLine("Connecting to " + d_host + ":" + d_port);
        Session session = new Session(sessionOptions);
        bool sessionStarted = session.Start();
        if (!sessionStarted)
        {
            System.Console.Error.WriteLine("Failed to start session.");
            return;
        }
```

and the error message:

> Reference Data/Bulk Reference Data Example
>   Connecting to localhost:8194
>   Failed to start session.
>   Press ENTER to quit

Comment: I have checked also that the port 8194 is open

Comment: Have you tried restarting the terminal?

Comment: I restarted the terminal, I work on visual studio with an example from bloomberg, FYI RLBPAPI on RStudio works fine on the same computer.

Comment: Same error if you don't use `sessionOptions`? (`Session session = new Session();`)

Comment: yes it is the same error

Comment: and you can see the bbcomm process running in your task manager?

Comment: If it is, you may want to launch your session with an EventHandler and listen to the messages received. You will probably get a SessoinStartupFailure with additional information. Or you may to contact Bloomberg's help desk directly - they should be able to help you troubleshoot the issue.

Comment: Are you able to use the Excel API? Does `=BDP("IBM US Equity","PX_LAST")` return a value in Excel?

Comment: Yes I am able to use Excel API , weird thing is I can use also RblpPAPI (so on R) API too